# Add two guard let in a prepare for segue function

Tags: swift, xcode, segue

I'm trying to build my first app with three tableViews which are hierarchical. The middle VC has two guard let in one prepare for segue function.

```swift
  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        guard let destination = segue.destination as? AddMemberViewController else {
            return
        }
        destination.club = club

        guard let Destination = segue.destination as? TransactionViewController, let selectedRow = self.tableViewMember.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row else {
            return
        }
        Destination.member = members[selectedRow]

    }
```

That's how it looks like. Can I fix this, that both func get used by my app, because it just uses the one on the top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is if you want to segue to TransactionViewController the function already returns because segue.destination is not AddMemberViewController.

Instead you should give your segues different identifiers and ask for them in `prepareForSegue`. Something like this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "AddMemberVCSegue" {
        guard let destination = segue.destination as? AddMemberViewController else {
            return
        }
        destination.club = club
    }

    if segue.identifier == "TransactionVCSegue" {
        guard let Destination = segue.destination as? TransactionViewController, let selectedRow = self.tableViewMember.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row else {
            return
        }
        Destination.member = members[selectedRow]
    }
}
```

Comment: Okey, Im gonna try this. Thank you very much :D

Comment: @TheClubApp if it is working and you like my answer i would appreciate it if you accept my answer :)

Comment: Glad i could help :)

Answer (score 2):

Just replace guards with if lets:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let destination = segue.destination as? AddMemberViewController {
       destination.club = club
    } else if let destination = segue.destination as? TransactionViewController, let selectedRow = self.tableViewMember.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row {
       destination.member = members[selectedRow]
    }     
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help :D

Answer (score 0):

`prepare(for` is called for **one** specific segue, so executing both `guard let` after another is unnecessarily expensive.

Usually you are checking the `identifier` of the segue with a `switch` statement, replace the literal identifiers with your real values

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
  switch segue.identifier {
     case "memberSegue":
        let destination = segue.destination as! AddMemberViewController
        destination.club = club
     case "transactionSegue":
        guard let selectedRow = self.tableViewMember.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row else { return }
        let destination = segue.destination as! TransactionViewController
        destination.member = members[selectedRow]
     default: break
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quickly answer .